# Read page messages

Tags: restfb

Im aware, that read_mailbox permission was removed in FB API>2.4. I need access to page related messages. So i have a page and someone is sending private message on this page (not directly to the user). Is there any API to read such messages?

So i need something like:

```
Connection<Conversation> conversations = facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/conversations", Conversation.class);
```

For page related messages,

Such API is available?

Best regards, KB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your use case.
The API you mention is already available, but you can only use it to read private Messages.
I suggest to use the messenger platform webhook. This can trigger a poll on `me/conversations` if you need the whole thread. If you are only interested in the content of the incoming message, you don't need your endpoint and work only with the messenger platform. Webhook + Send API may be enough: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform

Comment: Thanks for info! You mentioned that "The API you mention is already available". In version 9? When i tried to query private messages i received "Reading mailbox messages requires the extended permission read_mailbox (code 298, subcode null) 'null - null'". But there is no "read_mailbox" permission in version 9

Comment: probably closest is "pages_messaging". But even with this permission (i have it on my test user and the account is validated) im receiving this error. what additional permissions are needed to read conversations via resftfb library (using facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/conversations", Conversation.class))?

Comment: You need the `pages_messaging` and the `pages_manage_metadata` permissions and of course a page access token. You can also find this information in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v9.0/conversation